# Packer azure-arm: Cannot locate the managed image resource group

Tags: azure, packer

I am new to Packer and I have been trying to build my first packer on Azure image following this guide - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/build-image-with-packer

I did not follow the guide exactly as I already had a an Azure Subscription and resource group set up. But now when I attempt to build my Packer image I get the following error

```
Build 'azure-arm' errored: Cannot locate the managed image resource group myResourceGroup
```

From reading through the docs it states the only requirement is that the resource group already exist, which it does as I can see it in my Azure portal.

My packer json file follows the one from the guide which is shown below, any help appreciated

```
    {
  "builders": [{
    "type": "azure-arm",

    "client_id": "0831b578-8ab6-40b9-a581-9a880a94aab1",
    "client_secret": "P@ssw0rd!",
    "tenant_id": "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47",
    "subscription_id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "object_id": "a7dfb070-0d5b-47ac-b9a5-cf214fff0ae2",

    "managed_image_resource_group_name": "myResourceGroup",
    "managed_image_name": "myPackerImage",

    "os_type": "Windows",
    "image_publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
    "image_offer": "WindowsServer",
    "image_sku": "2016-Datacenter",

    "communicator": "winrm",
    "winrm_use_ssl": "true",
    "winrm_insecure": "true",
    "winrm_timeout": "3m",
    "winrm_username": "packer",

    "azure_tags": {
        "dept": "Engineering",
        "task": "Image deployment"
    },

    "location": "East US",
    "vm_size": "Standard_DS2_v2"
  }],
  "provisioners": [{
    "type": "powershell",
    "inline": [
      "Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server",
      "if( Test-Path $Env:SystemRoot\\windows\\system32\\Sysprep\\unattend.xml ){ rm $Env:SystemRoot\\windows\\system32\\Sysprep\\unattend.xml -Force}",
      "& $Env:SystemRoot\\System32\\Sysprep\\Sysprep.exe /oobe /generalize /shutdown /quiet"
    ]
  }]
}
```

Comment: well, are you sure all the credentials are correct? does sp have access to the resource group?

Comment: Yes, I think so. $sp has been assigned as a contributor in azure with ' New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Contributor -ServicePrincipalName $sp.ApplicationId'

Comment: I know , this is an old post. I too have the same issue. First of all, I have a doubt that , where should we run this script on the client machine or remote machine ? Also , we are not specifying any source from where the Image has to be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Build 'azure-arm' errored: Cannot locate the managed image resource
>   group myResourceGroup

According to this error message, it seems you have not replace your **resource group name** in that json file.

```
"managed_image_resource_group_name": "myResourceGroup",
```

We should **replace** that `myResourceGroup` with your **existing resource group name**, like this:

```
   "managed_image_resource_group_name": "jasonpacker",
```

Also we should replace `client_id`, `client_secret`, `tenant_id`, `subscription_id` and `object_id`.

After that complete, we can find the image in your existing resource group:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, I had done all this already. I just did not want to post my credentials for Azure online

Comment: @Ciaránimo ok, have you try it with another resource group name?

Comment: @Ciaránimo Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Thanks Jason, this helped me spot where I was going wrong.

Comment: Any hints as to what the issue was? I'm running into the same error, both with an existing resource group and one created for this use.

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me because my service principal has no sufficient permissions to read the resource group.

Make sure you have the correct permission, this should create a correct service principal:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --role Contributor --name sp-packer-001
```

Comment: Correct! Service Principal should be added as contributor on subscription level.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open issue with Packer where this error is displayed when there is a mismatch in the client_id / client_secret pair  for details see [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/5610)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too when trying to run packer through **Azure pipeline** of an **Azure Devops project** and my solution was:

1. Create an Azure compute gallery call it *GALLERY_NAME* within the resource group named *RESOURCE_GROUP* of the
   managed image
2. Create a VM image definition reference it here as *IMAGE_NAME* with version *IMAGE_VERSION*
3. Mention it in the packer template file(*image.pkr.hcl*) as the following:

   ```
   shared_image_gallery_destination {
   subscription         = SUBSCRIPTION_ID
   resource_group       = RESOURCE_GROUP
   gallery_name         = GALLERY_NAME
   image_name           = IMAGE_NAME
   image_version        = IMAGE_VERSION
   replication_regions = ["West Europe"]
   storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
   ```

   }